# How to make new given coordinates proportional to old ones?

Tags: c++, algorithm, resize

I have some object. It has some **original** width and height. I am given with **new** width and height. How to adopt **new** given width and height to object original ones? ( Say we had a square `1000x1000` and were given with some desired maximum possible coordinates say `1900x1200` what algorithm would produce `1200x1200` out of it? or in other case we had `1000x1000` original and were given with `400x600` it shall return `400x400`...)

So I started triing to create some code that would od it but failed with:

```
void resize_coefs(const int & original_w, const int & original_h, int & new_w, int & new_h)
{
    double VW = new_w; 
    double VH =  new_h;

    double rw = original_w/VW;
    double rh = original_h/VH;
    if (rw>=rh){
        new_h = VH;
        new_w = rh*new_w + 2;

    }
    else
    {
        new_w = VW;
        new_h= rw*new_h;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert windows screen coordinates to screenshot pixel coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385274/how-to-convert-windows-screen-coordinates-to-screenshot-pixel-coordinates)

Comment: Disagree with the duplicate flag. The other post describes how to scale the coordinate system for an image that has had its aspect ratio changed. OP is asking how to scale an image and retain its original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it this way:

1. Calculate the scaling factor for width.
2. Calculate the scaling factor for height.
3. Use the smallest scaling factor to scale both width and height.

Sample code:

```
void resize_coefs(const int original_w, const int original_h, int & new_w, int & new_h)
{
    double scale = std::min(
        ((double) new_w) / original_w ,
        ((double) new_h) / original_h );
    new_w = std::min( scale * original_w, new_w );
    new_h = std::min( scale * original_h, new_h );
}
```

Due to possible rounding errors, it is advisable to check that `new_w` and `new_h` are still within bounds after scaling.

EDIT: Here's a version that does the same thing with integer arithmetic only, using the hint that Kerrek provided in his answer. It's a little hard to see that it's following exactly the same logic.

```
void resize_coefs(const int original_w, const int original_h, int & new_w, int & new_h)
{
    int num, den;
    if (new_w * original_h < new_h * original_w) {
        num = new_w;
        den = original_w;
    } else {
        num = new_h;
        den = original_h;
    }
    new_w = original_w * num / den;
    new_h = original_h * num / den;
}
```

Comment: The danger of integer operations is that they may easily overflow. But if you are certain it won't happen, then your original clear code can be easily modified preserving clarity: `int scale = std::min(new_w * original_h, new_h * original_w );` and `new_w = scale / original_h;`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out the aspect ratio of the original and the new bounds. Then compare, and scale horizontal or vertical as appropriate:

```
const double orig_width, orig_height;
const double max_new_width, max_new_height;

const double orig_ar = orig_width / orig_height;
const double new_ar = max_new_width / max_new_height;

const double scale = new_ar < orig_ar ? max_new_width / orig_width : max_new_height / orig_height;

const double new_height = orig_height * scale;
const double new_width  = orig_width  * scale;
```

You can do this entirely with integers if you prefer. Remember that `a/b == c/d` is equivalent to `a*d == b*c` (and you even don't have to worry about zero in the denominator).

**Update:** Here's the concrete integer function I'd use:

```
void scale(unsigned int orig_width, unsigned int orig_height,
           unsigned int max_new_width, unsigned int max_new_height)
{
  const bool scale_width = max_new_width * orig_height < orig_width * max_new_height;

  const unsigned int new_height = scale_width ?
                                  orig_height * max_new_width / orig_width :
                                  orig_height * max_new_height / orig_height;
  const unsigned int new_width  = scale_width ?
                                  orig_width  * max_new_width / orig_width :
                                  orig_width  * max_new_height / orig_height;

  std::cout << "New dims: " << new_width << " x " << new_height << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Too many unnecessary floating point operations. Calculating the scale for width and height is more efficient.

Comment: @GeneBushuyev: As I said, this is just to show the maths. I'd write the actual implementation in pure integer operations.