# Position Mouse Wrong in openCV

Tags: opencv

When I clicked mouse on large images, position mouse wrong.
How to I get position when I clicked mouse on large image. But I don't like use cv_window_keepratio

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image that is larger than your display resolution, you need to **rescale** the image so it fits the window, else you will have problems trying to access pixels beyond the display.

[Simple arithmetics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5385402/176769) can convert a X,Y coordinate from one resolution to another, let's say, 800x600 to 1280x720.

Comment: You can give me details by 1 for example. I read links but i don't understand

Comment: My images is 1600 x 1000, my screen is 1366 x 768

Comment: Open the link I shared and take a good look at the code: it converts a given coordinate from the 800x600 resolution to 1280x720. Replace those numbers by the size of the rescaled image and it's original size.